# Ubuntu 15.04 and KDE4

Tags: kde, 15.04, kde4

Can I install KDE4 desktop on Ubuntu 15.04 using the terminal like the good 'old' days or will I have to go back to 14.04 LTS? KDE4 was beautiful.

***Edit:*** I don't want to roll back. I want to use KDE4 desktop on Ubuntu 15.04.